# Pass Data into .jsp Javascript array

Tags: javascript, json, jsp, google-maps-api-3

I have hard-coded data into a .jsp file. What I want to do is populate a JavaScript array with data sent from the server.

I have tried to send the data from another .jsp page, but I cannot figure out how to convert it into a JavaScript var for me to be able to use it in my page, I also have started using JSON objects, but before I continue I just need some guidance on what the best way to do this would be.

That is: populate a JavaScipt array on a .html or .jsp file from the server. The array will then be used for Google Maps API.

Let me know if you have any questions:

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's hardcoded, why not making it a JS variable directly?

```
var foo = [{
    "name1": "value1a",
    "name2": "value2a"
},{
    "name1": "value1b",
    "name2": "value2b"
}];
```

Or if it's hardcoded in Java side and you intend to use it in JS side as well, then convert the Java object to JSON using one of the many JSON serializers/parsers available. At the bottom of [json.org](http://json.org) you can find an overview of all available JSON APIs in Java. One of them is [Google Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/). It's able to convert for example a `List<SomeBean>` to a JSON string as follows

```
String jsonString = new Gson().toJson(someBeans);
```

You can then just let JSP print it as if it's a JS variable, assuming that it's stored as a request attribute:

```
var foo = ${jsonString};
```

Comment: +1, cleaner answer. Lazy to search, but will that escape representation of objects whose stringified version contains `</script>` ?

Comment: @Thrustmaster: Yes, Gson will by default JS-escape the bean properties. This is also configureable.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty simple:

1. You must make sure your JSP produces correct JavaScript as output.
2. Include the JSP with a `<script>` tag (i.e. the JSP needs to be accessible with a URL; put that URL into the `src` attribute).

Example for the JSP code:

```
var data = [<% ...generate array elements here... %>];
```

That will allow you to access the variable `data` in all JavaScript that is executed afterwards. In your case, you will include the script as the first thing in the page so every other script can use it.

Neat trick: Add a query parameter to specify the variable name:

```
var <%=request.getParameter("name") %> = [<% ...generate array elements here... %>];
```

and include it with

```
<script src="...url...?name=data" type="text/javascript">
```